# Remove string between pattern from file name using bash or sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a large set of .mp3 files which contain similar pattern of text attached to each file like this

`'Yethamaiyaa Yetham HD Extreme Quality .-V7NEP5gnTTY.mp3'`

where the actual track name is only

`'Yethamaiyaa Yetham.mp3'`

and this additional string

`'HD Extreme Quality .-V7NEP5gnTTY'` is attached to each file.

How do I remove this unnecessary string starting with `HD` and just before `.mp3`. The issue is that there is an additional dot `.` available between the marker strings. Also, the pattern of markers are same for all 400+ files. Any help to solve the issue is appriciated.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Look mah no ls :-) `for f in *.mp3; do echo mv -v -- "$f" "${f% HD*}.mp3"; done` , remove the echo if you want...

Comment: Thanks for the input. Good to know another way to do the job. But I have already done the job using accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls *.mp3 | sed  -n "s/^\(.*\) HD .*/mv -- '&' '\1.mp3'/p"  | bash
```

The above code uses `sed` to remove everything from " HD " to the end of the filename.  The portion of the filename  before " HD " is captured by the parens so it can be used later as `\1`.  The entire line is replaced with the required `mv` command.  I quoted it very carefully to account for the spaces in the filename.

If you want to see the commands it will perform without executing them, leave off the pipe to bash.

Preview commands:

```
ls *.mp3 | sed -n "s/^\(.*\) HD .*/mv -- '&' '\1.mp3'/p"
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: As per Cyrus' comment, `ls` output parsing is bad news - especially piping it to bash.  I think that for a quick and dirty script where you have previewed the file names and you are not in a potentially hostile environment, you should be ok with parsing the output of `ls`.  But the risks are there , and there's no possible way of coding around it - e.g. a fliename with a \n embedded.